# Is it possible to save the product key of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the product key that was used to activate Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/495794/how-can-i-find-the-product-key-that-was-used-to-activate-windows-8)

I have Windows 8 activated in my system. I don't have the product key of windows right now. Now I want to format my system again. Is there any way so that I can reuse the key? Is there any way I can get the key from an activated windows machine?

**Edit:**
I am not able to find the product key because I have used a MAK as my product key. Now I want the same to use it after formatting my disk. I found a software Volume Activation Manager tool on the windows website. I am not sure how to use it. Please tell me how can I reuse my key?

Comment: @Karan: I have added some more details. Now my case is different form the link.

Comment: Is it a MAK or KMS key? Where did you get hold of the volume license key anyway? The proper thing to do would be to contact your organization and ask them to help you out, which they obviously should if all's legit.

Comment: @DibyaRanjan where did you acquire said MAK in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

I found a site claiming to find lost product keys (I have no connection with them)
[Lost Product Keys](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/10-best-free-product-key-finders-1079718)

I am also wondering if the product key is stored somewhere in the registry, after all, how do these tools find it?  My point it must be possible to do what you want, just a question of more time for research versus spending money to get the job done.

The Microsft legalities of what you do keep changing. 
A) You could ring them!  
B) I think it's OK providing you reformat the old machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the product key of your Windows installation, I would suggest to install [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html), a free online tool which gives you all the information about your PC **including your license key**.

Now, obviously, you'll ask me why you should install a complete system information tool just to know your product key instead of a standalone product key finder. I have tried other product key finder utilities like Magic Key Finder and some others (the ones in the first page of Google search results) but unfortunately none of them has told me the correct product key of my Window 8 installation (I was just checking, my product key is written on a paper and kept in my room).

This utility, however, told me the correct key of my system. So, just download it, run it and in the results, scroll down to software licenses and voila, your key is there.

[image: Product Keys]

Point to note: It didn't return the product keys for my Kaspersky (For Kaspersky, it only showed the Product ID and not the product key) and Office, so in case you want these, you have to look elsewhere.

Another point to note: If you have installed the Media Center Pack on your PC, the Windows 8 product key will be the key for the Media Center addon you added. And, no, this won't work when you're reinstalling Windows. Instead, look in the key which shows for Internet Explorer. This is the actual key you used during installation. I can confirm, in my case, it was the same key with which I installed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Pratyush but Belarc Advisor is not giving my product key.

Comment: What does it say? Are you using version 8.3?

Comment: I got result as:  Microsoft - Windows 8 Enterprise (x64) 00178-50352-23007-AA843 (Key: BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBFDP)

Comment: Umm does it say the same for Internet Explorer as well?

Comment: You could try this http://www.magicaljellybean.com/ But the reason I didn't recommend this is that in Windows 8 it showed me my key as BBBBB... basically what you're getting in Belarc.

Comment: But you can try it out nevertheless

Comment: Sorry.. I can't find the keys as Guy thomas said I tried all 10 of them still not able to find.

Comment: All of them say BBBBB?

Comment: Yes all of them say BBBBB

Comment: I tried the same software on other PC and is working fine so +1

Comment: If you have found it useful, please upvote the answer to help others in the future

Comment: The upvote this answer is having is given by me..

Comment: Oh alright! Sorry :) And thanks for the upvote :) You should also try magicandre's solution given below

Answer (score 1):

use the tool [**Windows 8 Product Key Viewer**](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/30363-Windows-8-WDP-Product-Key-Viewer). This seams to be the only tool to read the key in Windows 8.