# Where is the Microsoft Office 2012 Key?

Tags: product-key, microsoft-office-2013

I want to wipe Windows 8 and install Windows 7 on my machine, but I don't have the key for Microsoft Office 2013 to reinstall it afterward.  Is there a way I can retrieve it?

I'll download an application if necessary, but if anyone knows where in the registry it is (if that's where it is) I can just look it up myself.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you purchased the software from usually has a record of the key you were assigned. If you review your order history you might be able to find it this way. I tend to find this to be the easier way. If you purchased a disc the key is typically on the box or the case the disc was contained in.

Otherwise you will need to use a software like in the article below:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/246040/how_to_find_your_windows_or_office_product_key.html

Also earlier post asked a similar question so you can look to there answers for guidance:

[How to find Windows 8 product key?](https://superuser.com/questions/495794/how-can-i-find-the-product-key-that-was-used-to-activate-windows-8)