# Why is Windows telling me my product key is invalid because it contains zeros?

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

I'm trying to reinstall Windows 8 on my main machine, and after downloading the installer, it asked for my key.

I looked inside the "System" screen in control panel, which listed my key.

However, when I tried to enter this key into the serial key box in the installer, it's telling me that zero's cannot be in my key, even though this contradicts what control panel is telling me.

What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find Windows 8 product key?](http://superuser.com/questions/495794/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Product ID and Serial Number are not the same thing. *IF* you got your Windows 8 License with your computer when you bought it, the Serial Number is mostly located on a Windows-Sticker on your device. As far as I know there are some roundabout ways to get your key, but you can't just type it off as far as I remember.

Comment: yes one is all-numbers with six digits each group, one is mixed-alphanumerics, 5x5 characters